# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu with different styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a small project and I need to use drop-down list, I saw a nice dropdown list without default styling.

What I need just to show how I can make the same.

Example : http://teachyourselftocode.com/

Comment: You can always check the source code by adding "view-source:" to the beginning of the URL (view-source:http://teachyourselftocode.com/) or right clicking on that page and clicking view source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just take the same library and the same script include your project
try this

Link :
http://teachyourselftocode.com/assets/application-7790babf84d03a6beaea0c9e188a7514.css

Script:
http://teachyourselftocode.com/assets/application-c004d1f31767f20710957a4ef632ec32.js

Answer (score 0):

In here you will find the way its easy to implement

> http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Example:Run this with bootstrap CDN

```
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope you get what you need :)

Comment: This is basic from bootstrap, what is required is different. 
However i really appreciate your help

Comment: Thank you @Akitha_MJ, I know how it's working with basics but I need it without styling and I got it. appreciate your help.